# Get max value from a list with lists?

Tags: python, list, function, python-2.7, max

So I have a list that contains several list which all have three strings first, then one float number, like:

```
resultlist = [["1", "1", "a", 8.3931], ["1", "2", "b", 6.3231], ["2", "1", "c", 9.1931]]
```

How do I make a function that returns the maximum value (which here would be 9.1931)? I tried

```
def MaxValue():
    max_value = max(resultlist)
    return max_value
```

but that just gives me a list.

EDIT: Also, any way I could get the index for where the value comes from? Like, from which sublist?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Loop through your outer list and select the last element of each sublist:

```
def max_value(inputlist):
    return max([sublist[-1] for sublist in inputlist])

print max_value(resultlist)
# 9.1931
```

It's also best if you keep all function related variables in-scope (pass the list as an argument and don't confuse the namespace by reusing variable names).

Comment: you get the last element because you know that lists are ordered and the last element is always the bigger in each list ??

Comment: @EmiliOrtega This answer is very specific to the question---"I have a list that contains several list which all have three strings first, then one float number"---so this solution gets the last element because that's where the number is.

Comment: yess what I mean is that if you would have a list [["1", "1", "a", 10, 8.3931], ....] like that one, it would still return 8.3 instead of 10 right ?

Comment: Correct.  `sublist[-1]` returns the last value in each sublist.  It has nothing to do with sortedness.

Answer (score 16):

In perhaps a more functional than pythonic manner:

```
>>> max(map(lambda x: x[3], resultlist))
9.1931
```

It begins by mapping each element of result list to the number value and then finds the max.

The intermediate array is:

```
>>> map(lambda x: x[3], resultlist)
[8.3931000000000004, 6.3231000000000002, 9.1930999999999994]
```

Answer (score 13):

Numpy helps with numerical nested lists. Try this:

```
resultlist = [[3, 2, 4, 4], [1, 6, 7, -6], [5, 4, 3, 2]]
max(resultlist)  # yields [5, 4, 3, 2] because 5 is the max in: 3, 1, 5
np.max(resultlist)  # yields 7 because it's the absolute max
```

`max()` returns the list which first element is the maximum of all lists' first element, while `np.max()` returns the highest value from all the nested lists.

Comment: This absolutely should be the accepted answer - it provides a general solution, not the super-specific-to-the-current-list-setup solution offered by the accepted answer.

Comment: @Jona I disagree. I find this solution quite useful (I am using it right now in a project) but it has two drawbacks namely 1)it depends on `numpy` and 2)it requires a conversion of the data (even though the given code might suggest otherwise internally `numpy.max()` works with `numpy` array data). There are cases where this is too much of an overhead. If the OP is using `numpy` (which is not the case), this would have been the best solution since it's out-of-the-box. The accepted solution offers a generic Python code that has no external dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

```
resultlist = [["1", "1", "a", 8.3931], ["1", "2", "b", 6.3231], ["2", "1", "c", 9.1931]]
print(max(map(lambda x: x[-1],resultlist)))
```

Output:

```
9.1931
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want the index too you can use `enumerate` with `operator.itemgetter` using `map`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
def max_val(l, i):
    return max(enumerate(map(itemgetter(i), l)),key=itemgetter(1)))
```

Which will return a tuple of the max with the index:

```
In [7]: resultlist = [["1", "1", "a", 8.3931], ["1", "2", "b", 6.3231], ["2", "1", "c", 9.1931]]

In [8]: max_val(resultlist, -1)
Out[8]: (2, 9.1931)
```

Or just a regular gen exp:

```
from operator import itemgetter
def max_val(l, i):
    return max(enumerate(sub[i] for sub in l), key=itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: +1 for "itemgetter". However, I think there is something wrong with the first definition of the function "max_val", at least I receive a SyntaxError - I guess there is something wrong with the parantheses.

Comment: Could you remove it - I do not have enough reputation to edit it!? ;)

Comment: Ok, well, it will appear at some point. But nice solution! I now incorporated the itemgetter in my solution below as well.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to just get the maximum number from the floats (the last index in your list)? If so, here's a solution.

```
last_indices = [x[3] for x in resultlist]
return max(last_indices)
```

Comment: Why use `sorted()[0]` instead of `max()`?  That's a huge performance hit to sort the list only to get the biggest value.

Comment: @wflynny I edited my answer because you actually posted your comment, haha.

Comment: how about the index?

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, you can answer this inquiry in more general terms (even without additional libraries).

```
maxval = max(map(max, resultlist))
print(maxval)
```

This takes the inner list with the maximum value, then maps the max function on that inner list to find the maximum value and stores it in maxval.

Comment: How to get rid of the warning "Expected type Iterable, got _dict_values instead"?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer just in case you get a list of list where the number is not always on the 3rd position:

```
from itertools import chain
max(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, long, float)), chain.from_iterable(resultlist)))
```

What is going on? `itertools.chain` flattens the list of lists, the `filter` then selects all the numeric values of which the maximal value is then determined using the `max` function.
Advantage here is that it also works for arbitrary lists of lists where the numeric value can be found anywhere in the list.

For your example:

```
resultlist = [['1', '1', 'a', 8.3931], ['1', '2', 'b', 6.3231], ['2', '1', 'c', 9.1931]]
max(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, long, float)), chain.from_iterable(resultlist))) 
#prints 9.1931
```

One more general example:

```
myList = [[23, 34, 'a'],['b'],['t', 100]]
max(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, long, float)), chain.from_iterable(myList)))
#prints 100
```

EDIT:

If you also want to get the index of the maximal value, you can do the following (using @Padraic Cunningham approach):

```
from itertools import chain
import operator
resultlist = [['1', '1', 'a', 8.3931], ['1', '2', 'b', 6.3231], ['2', '1', 'c', 9.1931]]
l = filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, long, float)), chain.from_iterable(resultlist))
# l: [8.3931, 6.3231, 9.1931]
max(enumerate(l), key = operator.itemgetter(1))
#(2, 9.1931)
```

This approach assumes that there is exactly one numeric value per list!

One more example using a list where the numeric value is on an arbitrary position:

```
from itertools import chain
import operator
myList = [[23, '34', 'a'],['b', 1000],['t', 'xyz', 100]]
l=filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, long, float)), chain.from_iterable(myList))
max(enumerate(l), key = operator.itemgetter(1))
#prints (1, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the answer is using list comprehensions:

```
>>> max([x[3] for x in resultlist])
9.1931
```